# Highlighting specific bars on click d3

Tags: d3.js

I have a negative stacked bar chart that onclick displays an image associated with that bar. The bars also change color onhover. What I am trying to do is also reverse that effect so that when a user clicks on the image, all the bars associated with that image will change to the hovered color.

Updated dataset:

```
 var ratiodata = [[{y:4.2, corr:"682825.jpg"},{y:3.7, corr: "682791.jpg"},{y:3.3, corr:"682825.jpg"},{y:2.7, corr: "682759.jpg"}],

               [{y:-1.9},{y:-1.3},{y:-1.5},{y:-1.2}]]

 var wordcount =[ [4.2, 22, -1.9, 10, 518, ["682825.jpg"]],
              [3.7, 41, -1.3, 14, 1117, ["682791.jpg"]],
              [3.3, 28, -1.5, 13, 857, ["682825.jpg"]],
              [2.7, 27, -1.2, 12, 1010, ["682759.jpg"]]             
                        ];
```

Updated onclick:

```
var s;
            d3.select("#VGcorrsbox")
              .selectAll("img")
              .data(wordcount[i][5])
              .enter()
              .append("img")
              .classed("VGcorrs",true)
              .attr("src", wordcount[i][5])             
              .on("click", function(d,i) 
            {
                    for (var i = 0; i < wordcount.length; i++){      
                         if(s){
                            s="";
                            d3.selectAll(".series")
                            d3.selectAll(".bar")
                            .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i)})    
                         }
                          else {                                 
                         s = d3.select(this).attr("src")
                            d3.selectAll(".series")
                            d3.selectAll(".bar")
                              .filter(function(d,i) {
                                return d.corr == s;
                              })
                             .style("fill", "#C79E4C"); 

                          }
                    }
            });
```

Comment: You will have to filter the bars that you are setting the color for based on what's highlighted.

Comment: I updated my code but now the only the first 2 bars are highlighted regardless of the image clicked, and I'm getting an undefined for the y values of those bars?

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example please?

Comment: I've edited my code to include everything. Also, now only the top bars are getting highlighted. I'm assuming it's because it's broken? Thank you!

Comment: I've tried to put your code in a jsfiddle but I can't seem to get it to run properly. In particular I don't see any pictures and `d3.tip` isn't defined -- where does that Javascript file come from?

Comment: I got d3.tip from here: http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579. I also just removed overlay.js from the code.

Comment: I solved this by changing my data.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as an answer for reference?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my code. It is an ugly solution, but it works.